# MVC3 Publishing, why models/controllers don't get published

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller, publishing

I am attempting to publish an MVC3 Site in Visual Studio 2010 using the "File System" publish method.  The MVC site does not work, but I'm almost positive that this has something to do with my current server configuration, so my question is **not** why won't the site work.  My question is when i publish the site, it does not publish the "Models" or "Controllers" folders; is this normal?  If so how does the site function without these two elements being built to the server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is normal.  Your models and controller are compiled and placed in folder called "bin".  There should be a DLL in that folder with the name of your project.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was going on.  So I guess my next question is this, if another web developer comes to work on these applications behind me (like I leave my company) how will he/she be able to edit them without those files?

Comment: Well, hopefully you have the source code in place that will be accessible to them (a git or svn repository).  In the worst case scenario they could decompile using something like this: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP